# java Object in mxGraph

Tags: java, mxgraph

I've found this example to have user object as mxCell values in a mxGraph

https://github.com/jgraph/jgraphx/blob/master/examples/com/mxgraph/examples/swing/UserObject.java

But I don't understand how to use java objects instead of XML nodes; it says :

```
        // When using Java objects as user objects, make sure to add the
        // package name containg the class and register a codec for the user
        // object class as follows:
        //
        // mxCodecRegistry.addPackage("com.example"); 
        // mxCodecRegistry.register(new mxObjectCodec(
        //  new com.example.CustomUserObject()));
```

I thougth I have to encode decode with an mxCodec by :

```
mxCodec encoder = new mxCodec();
myObject o = new myObject();
graph.insertVertex(parent, null, value = encoder.encode(o), x, y, width, height, style);
```

And decoded when needed by :

```
mxCell cell = // getting a cell from graph 
mxCodec decoder = new mxCodec();
myObject o = decoder.decode((org.w3x.dom.Node)cell.getValue());
```

However this method doesnt work, can anyone tell me how it should be done ?